# Resizing a polar coordinate image

Tags: python, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have an image from weather radar which is in polar coordinates (azimuth, range).
Normal resizing functions are not working as they presume the image in Cartesian coordinate I guess. From scikit-image etc.

How can I resize the image effectively having same ratio and characteristics maintained as we get in Cartesian. Or the only way is to convert to Cartesian and then back ?

Original (masked array) displayed using weather lib:
[image: nexrad]

Polar Cordinates Contour based:

[image: contour]

resized the array (and plotted using imshow)
[image: imshow]

Resizing the third graph works well but I need resized version of the first polar coordinates.

Comment: Could you provide an example file/code for the image and provide examples for resizing functions you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Also, regardless of the details of the package you're using, resizing polar coordinates just comes down to rescaling the radial coordinate.

Comment: All depends on the position of the center of the polar coordinate system. If the center coincides with that of the image then based on the Thales theorem, simply multiply the distance to origin by the same scale factor. Otherwise you will need to perform a translation while remaining in polar or convert to Cartesian and then back.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up saving it as a plot and resizing using skimage with usual functions. Not so perfect but works.