# RGBA Color to data value from a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a color coded plot. 
Normally, to get RGBA color from the data value, I could use `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` instance for `to_rgba(value)`.

In current situation, I want to reverse it to have a function like `to_value(rgba)`.

Is there any function or ideas on how to proceed with this?

Comment: There are many possible mappings from RGBA to a scalar value, you'll have to pick one. (Algebra on the four RGBA values.) What format is the plot in? How are you going to get the RGBA values?

Comment: Actually I don't think this is easily possible. Given a colormap, `to_rgba(value)` can simply look up the value in the given range of the colormap and return the respective color, it's a unique scalar to scalar map. However `to_value(rgba)` would be a mapping of a vector of shape 4 to a scalar and it's not trivial to find out where in the colormap your color is. Also, it's a non-unique map (if you think about colormaps like 'prism' or 'flag'). There may however be a solution for your specific case, so you may want to share more details about why you'd need that mapping.

Comment: I have normal radar based maps with color coded intensities. See this question for relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259051/resizing-a-polar-coordinate-image.  The reason is that I need cartesian coordinates from polar coordinates. Easiest approach I found was to use plotting libraries and then use the plotted maps but now I need raw values back from plotted maps. Let me know if this is not clear.